# CSS max-height : auto doesnt work and a jQuery issue. why?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

i have this little gallery which is generated from the php code below. And the other thing is that id like to make these images "big" when hovering it. jQuery function is below.

[image]

this script doesnt work i also have other script in the same scripts.js file, could it be the : issue?

```
$(document).ready(function() 
$(".thumbnail img").mouseover(function() {
$(this).css("cursor","pointer");
$(this).animate({width:"500px"},"slow");
});
});
```

php function which creates the gallery

```
  function showGallery()
{

$galleryHTML = "<ul>";
$images = new DirectoryIterator("pildid");
foreach($images as $image) {
$file = $image -> current();
$filename = $file -> getFilename();
$src = "pildid/$filename";
$info = new Finfo( FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE );
$type = $info->file($src);
$galleryhtml = "";
if($type ==="image/jpeg")

    $galleryhtml ="<li><img src='$src' height='100px' width='120px'/></li>";
    echo $galleryhtml;
}

 $galleryhtml = "</ul>";
 include_once('view/galerii.php');
```

}

Comment: You might want to split your question into three separate questions if you have problems in each separate language...

Comment: Well its a single page which uses them all so i thought it would be easy to understand.

Comment: For the jQuery, you have an extra pair of parenthesis between `.mouseover` and its function.

Comment: `max-height/width:auto` is unnecessary, as they are `auto` by default.

Comment: @Jason: Actually, `auto` isn't a valid value for min/max-width/height at all. It is only valid on `width` and `height`. The default value of min is `0`, and the default value of max is `none` (i.e. there is no upper limit).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$(".thumbnail img").mouseover(function() {
$(this).css("cursor","pointer");
$(this).animate({width:"500px"},"slow");
});
```

And this:

```
overflow: hidden; //Wrong
```

Should be:

```
overflow:scroll;
```